# test group of element & apply same settings

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check properties for groups of divs and apply them style changes. I create groups by adding an attribute called "group" like this:

```
<div id="div1" group="1">...</div>
<div id="div2" group="1">...</div>
<div id="div3">...</div>
```

So div 1 and 2 belong to the same group.

Now I would like to check if any div from group 1 has a position:fixed. What I'm currently doing is using .each to check if there is match.

Question1: is there a better option to do this?

```
$("[group]").each(function()
{
   if ($(this).css("position") === "fixed") 
      {
         myvar = 1;
      }
});
```

With myvar = 1 I know that one element in the group has a fixed position. If I now wanted to apply a different style to each element of the group, how should I do it? If I have a lot of elements, going through all of them could become a performance issue no?

Question2: how can I apply a style to all elements of my group? Again with each?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: _"how can I apply a style to all elements of my group? "_ Do you want to apply the same style to each element? Perhaps consider using `data-*` attribute, that is `data-group` instead of `group` attribute

Comment: I am puzzled why you don't just give the elements a class-name, rather than a 'group', and then just style the class? If you need to iterate them then this can be based on their class-name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by grouping the element by group number,

```
$("[group]").each(function() {
 if($(this).css("position") === "fixed") {
   $("[group='" + $(this).attr("group") + "']").css("style","someStyle");
 }
});
```

And if you want to apply different styles to each element then iterate the elements collected by using group number, one by one by using `.each()`.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fsmhqzuu/)

Answer (score 1):

> Question1: is there a better option to do this?

You can use `data-*` attributes, `.filter()`

html

```
<div id="div1" data-group="1">...</div>
<div id="div2" data-group="1">...</div>
<div id="div3">...</div>
```

js

```
var fixed = $("[data-group=1]").filter(function() {
              return $(this).css("position") === "fixed"
            });
fixed.css(/* prop, value */);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. Will your suggestion apply the style to all elements in the group or just the one with fixed position?

Comment: @user3638239 `fixed` variable should include elements having `data-group=1` attribute and `position:fixed`. If you want to apply style to all elements having `data-group` attribute you can use selector `$("[data-group]")`. `.filter()` filters elements which return `true` in function, `.each()` iterates all elements within original selector

Comment: ok understood, fixed should only help me to identify if the first condition is met and if it's the case, I should use your second suggestion to apply the same style too all. Thanks

Comment: @user3638239 Yes. `fixed` variable 1) filters elements having `data-group=1` attribute; and 2) `css` `position:fixed`. `fixed` collection should contain only elements that satisfy 1), and 2)